# Email verification for ios app registration using parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, email-verification

How and where can i put an if function in which it tests if the user's email is verified or no, if verified login the user, if not show an error?
thank you

Comment: If you have email verification turned on you can get valueForKey:"emailVerified" on an instance of PFUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution:

```
if(PFUser.currentUser()["emailVerified"].isEqual(1))    
    {
    //let the user login
    }
else
    {
    //don't let the user login
    }
```